# How to get rid of 'Content-type: text/html' in PHP script output?

Tags: php

I am running a PHP script as a cron job. An email is fired iff the script generates an output. Unfortunately, even if it does not output anything, an email is fired with:

```
Content-type: text/html
```

How can I get rid of this automatic `Content-type: text/html` generation triggering an email?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `-q` switch on the php command:

```
php -q whatever.php
```

This stands for "quiet", and will prevent php from outputting web headers that it normally would.

Alternatively, if you want to be explicit and more verbose, you can use `--no-header`:

```
php --no-header whatever.php
```

Source: [PHP Manual: Command line options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)